# Citrix Connection Issues from Azure VM's

Tags: azure, citrix

My question isn't about Citrix , but rather the impact adding a public IP address to an Azure VM has in how it interacts with websites and internet based applications

I have a number of Azure virtual machines that connect to a remote applications using the Citrix Workspace client. I was having an issue where the application would fail to start, freeze or simply show a black screen until I discovered that enabling and assigning a public IP address to the network interface of the VM resolved the issue - but I do not know why. After doing so the application loads quickly and consistently all the time.

These VM's sit in a standard vnet and are not behind a load balancer - although the same results are seen when they are added to the backend pool of a public load balancer.

What changes on a VM when it has an assigned IP address? Is there a difference in how traffic breaks out?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference when you assign a public IP to a VM, or you put it behind an LB with a public IP, is that the VM uses this IP for outbound traffic.

A VM with no public IP will get an outbound IP assigned randomly by Azure, which you have no control over or visibility of and which can change ay any point. Once you assign a public IP the VM will use this IP as it's outbound IP address consistently.

Why this would affect your Citrix connection, I am not sure. The fact that the IP is now static may be impacting things.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's very strange behavior - I fixed the issue but I'm also hoping to figure out what I've actually fixed.